# Can we merged ResearchKit and CareKit project into one project?

Tags: ios, researchkit, carekit

I want to merge Research Kit open source sample into Carekit open source sample. What is the possible way to perform this into a single project? Is this possible??

Comment: The answer may depend on your end goal. What are you trying to accomplish by merging them together?

Comment: Yes. This is possible. I did it and achieved my goal :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The Carekit Sample app requires you to have ResearchKit. 
You can embed researchkit manually, or you can clone Carekit with recursive submodules. 
Also, can you elaborate a little what you mean by merging RK sample into CK sample?